# Cleditor: How put toolbar in two lines

Tags: jquery, editor, cleditor

I need that toolbar of Cleditor is in two lines, my code is:

```
var list = [txtDescripcion, txtRecomendacion, txtEfecto];
var controls_ = "bold italic underline strikethrough subscript superscript | font size 

var options = {
    height: 172,
    width: 309,
    controls: "bold italic underline subscript superscript | font size " +
                "  | color highlight | bullets numbering |" +
                " alignleft center alignright justify | undo redo | " +
                " cut copy paste pastetext";
}

$.each(list, function (i, elem) {
    var editor = this.cleditor(options);
    editor[0].focus();
```

thank's for u help!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: to generate the editor, the toolbar is rendered in a line and buttons that do not take that line onto a second, but apparently assumes that the toolbar is still just a line.